# Egg Whites Won't Stiffen

Tags: eggs, egg-whites

I was making Waffles the other day, and was whipping egg whites in a plastic Tupperware, but after an extremely long time, they hadn't stiffened. I looked in the special help section of my cookbook to find out why and I noticed that it says that egg whites can be beaten in glass or metal, but not plastic.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Whilst not necessarily a duplicate, this is a relevant answer: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/11341/65470
If you want an explanation from the  chemical standpoint, I'll search/write one up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is virtually impossible to get every last trace of grease/oil out of plastic containers.

Egg whites will not whip with even the slightest trace of oil/grease anywhere in the bowl, on the beaters, etc.

Ergo, plastic and whipped egg whites do not go together.